# How to denote Java versions correctly?

Tags: java, version, java-8

I've seen three possible Java version notations, e.g. Java 8 may be written in the following ways:

- Java 8
- Java 8 SE
- java 1.8

Which is the correct one? I mean which one is usable in academic writing?.

Similar problem with JDK and JRE

Comment: What is considered the right form has changed over time. i.e. it was `Java 1.4.2` => `Java 5.0` => `Java 6`  As long as it is clear it not such a problem.  If you see `Java 4` or `Java 2 1.4`, they are less desirable.

Comment: The reason it has changed is for marketing reasons.  Marketing likes to keep things simple and clean e.g. `Java SE 8`.  On the runtime time side they try to make things as back ward compatible i.e. `1.8` as the first version was `1.0` and people really did write code to check for `1.` in the version so we are stuck with it apparently.

Comment: Official docs here: [Java Platform, Standard Edition 8 Names and Versions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk8-naming-2157130.html)

Comment: @Jesper thanks, that's exactly the source I was looking for :)

Comment: Note also that JDK version numbering will change in the future. See [Project Verona](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/verona/) and [JEP-223](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing about [Java Standard Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html), then the correct notation will be: `Java SE 8`, the same rule applies for Enterprise Edition (`Java EE 7`).

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 and Java 1.8 are the same and Java 8 SE is standard Edition. Java 8 is good for academic writing.

Answer (score 2):

The Java naming and versioning convention is unfortunately complicated.  In fact, java versioning has its own [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history).

### Versioning

Java started off its life in 1.0 and 1.1 in the mid 90s.  When Java 1.2 was releases it was branded as "Java 2".  We had to live with the next few releases with this dual numbering scheme until Java 1.5 when the "1." prefix was dropped and 1.5 officially became 5.0.

Java 8 being referred to as "Java 1.8" is an artifact of this history.

### Java Editions

Java SE, the [Java Platform, Standard Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition) (also known as J2SE until Java 5) is the Java platform used for java desktop and server programs.  Java SE is what most people mean when talking about Java.

Other "Editions" are [Java ME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition) (Micro Edition) which is a cut down version of Java for embedded devices (including phones) and [Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) (Enterprise Edition) which provides extra libraries on top of Java SE including Java [Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), [EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ejb/info), [JMS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jms/info) and others used in [Java Application Servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server#Java_application_servers).

### JRE vs JDK

- JRE: Java Runtime Edition
- JDK: [Java Development Kit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit)

Simply, the JRE is able to run Java progams; the JDK is used to build Java programs.

### See Also

- [Why java is now known as java2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985820/why-java-is-now-known-as-java2)?
- [What is the difference between JVM, JDK, JRE & OpenJDK?](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CF8QFjAL&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F11547458%2Fwhat-is-the-difference-between-jvm-jdk-jre-openjdk&ei=HrdEVZqOLuO3mAWVo4HIAw&usg=AFQjCNGQ_iUHdLLAtPZqDtLY8Jdm9fOsTQ&sig2=pdrjYtIfjADq73bA3UMiag&bvm=bv.92291466,d.dGY)

Answer (score 1):

Three of them are valid notations. There is no right or wrong all of them are used.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using either one of the options should make any difference. All convey the same thing and anyone using Java will know this.

However if you are concerned about academic writing then you can use

- Java SE 8

and give reference as [Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29) :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the java spec, java versions can be denoted as java 1.x.x
Java Standard edition (correct notation is Java SE 7)

JDK version can be represented as JDK 1.x.x, similar to JRE as x. 
(If the version of JDK is (1.7.0) then the JRE version to be 7)